# Python open text file, do multiline regular expressions, write out file

Tags: python, regex, output, multiline

I have spent years in the 90s doing regular expressions on Perl but have been out of IT since and am a Python newbie. What syntactical wrappers do I need to do the job in Python? This is where I am at now, the result is the computer doing nothing and that is it.:

```
import os
import re
os.chdir("/Users/.../")
atext = open("textfile.txt", 'r').read()
atext = re.sub(r'foo', r'bar', atext.rstrip())
print atext
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: maybe supply some (brief) example input - and explain what you expect the output to be

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `.read()` will not read whole file, it reads file by given size in bytes: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

What you actually need, is to read your file line by line, you can use `atext.readlines()` which will return your whole file lines in a list, or use this code which is actually faster than `.readlines()`

```
import os
import re
os.chdir("/Users/.../")
with open("textfile.txt", 'r') as atext:
    for line in atext:
        line = re.sub(r'foo', r'bar', line.rstrip())
        print line
```

Comment: Thank you. That got me much closer and somebody else gave me this answer which did the trick:<br><br>
`import re<br>
INPUT = 'in.txt'<br>
OUTPUT = 'out.txt'<br>
<br>
with open(INPUT, 'r') as input_file:<br>
  data = input_file.read().strip()<br>
<br>
data = re.sub(r'a', r'b', data)<br><br>
#  more replacements go here<br>

with open(OUTPUT, 'w') as output_file:<br>
  output_file.write(data)<br>`